# Comparison with "the ... the" structure

Tags: comparison

I just wonder the following sentence is correct or not:
"The better the weather **is**, the better we feel."
since I usually hear things like:
"The better the weather, the better we feel."
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

> - (1) The better the weather is, the better we feel.
> - (2) The better the weather, the better we feel.

Sentences (1) and (2) are both grammatically valid, and have the same meaning. A fluent speaker might well use either, and would understand either. Sentence (2) could be considered a shortened form of (1). Such constructions are common.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is perfectly natural and common too.

For example,

> [...the better the work is the less visible it is...](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Invisible_Work_of_Nurses/o3NeBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22the%20better%20the%20work%20is%22)

> [...the better the work is the better it sells.](https://books.google.com/books?id=pwcUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&dq=%22the+better+the+work+is,+the+better%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj7wILc--f7AhVKGlkFHRvuAIsQ6AF6BAgHEAI)

> [...the higher the pressures are, the better the prognosis is.](https://books.google.com/books?id=JBF5jlaRClcC&pg=PA1227&dq=%22the+better+the+prognosis+is%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiw3ZuL_Of7AhXRp3IEHWqWBH0Q6AF6BAgIEAI)